# How to write the preamble into a file

Tags: external-files, preamble

Can one define a bunch of macros, include them in a LaTeX source file
`main.tex` and after issuing

```bsh
$ latex main.tex
```

find the preamble of `main.tex` in a file, say `main.nem` ?

It is a requirement, that the source `main.tex` does not have to
be touched by me.
So, I receive a file `main.tex`, that already includes the magic
macros, that I ask for in this question.
And all I have to do, is to compile the file and have the preamble in
a file.
The burden for the author of `main.tex` shall not be greater than
to include the file with the magic macros in them.
It is not allowed, to ask the author to use a special documentclass,
or have to write

```
\begin{filecontents}...
```

or some such into it.
The only trace of me, using his file, is

```
\input{magic_macros.tex}
```

somewhere in his preamble.

I can do a somewhat analogous sort of thing with macros that I define, and
that has proven to be extremely useful in my application domain.

A stripped down example of it is:

#### `macros.tex`:

```
\newwrite\nemWrite
\immediate\openout\nemWrite=\jobname.nem
\newtoks\nemToks
\newcommand{\toNem}[1]{%
    \nemToks={#1}
    \immediate\write\nemWrite{\the\nemToks}
}
\newcommand{\question}[1]{%
    \toNem{#1}%
    {#1}%
}
```

#### `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{macros.tex}
\begin{document}
\question{%
    What does $2+2$ evaluates to?
}
```

I was hoping that there exists something similar for the preamble.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) How is this different from a document class?

Comment: It's not very clear. You already have the preamble in another file.

Comment: At TX.SX we don't usually place a signature or thanks since these are already given in your profile view and whenever you upvote an answer or accept one.

Comment: Follow-up Question: [How to write the `\documentclass` into a file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79042/how-to-write-the-documentclass-into-a-file).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [the `standalone` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone) to extract the preamble for you.    Given a complete document as in the `main.tex` below, you run `pdflatex` on `mainPreamble.tex` which is defined as follows:

### `mainPreamble.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \input{main}
    \typeout{Sub preamble is now in \jobname.sta.}
    Sub preamble is now in \jobname.sta.
\end{document}
```

This extracts the preamble to the file `mainPreamble.sta`.  Then in you other document where you need to use this preamble you simply use:

```
\UsePackage{main}
```

and the extracted preamble from `main.tex` is used.  So, the MWE below yields:

[image]

which used the definition of `question` as originally defined in `main.tex`.

## Note:

- This required me to do some hacking in `\UsePackage` as I am not that familiar with this particular usage of the `standalone` package. So, perhaps that can be simplified, but I believe this does what you require.

### `main.tex`:

```
%% This is main.tex
\documentclass{article}
%% This is the preamble of main.tex
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\question}[1]{%
    \textbf{Question:}~#1%
}

\begin{document}
\question{%
    What does $2+2$ evaluates to?
}
```

### Code:

Following is to be run only **after** compiling `mainPreamble.tex` as it needs `mainPreamble.sta`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\UsePackage}[1]{%
    \let\standalonepreambles\relax
    \let\endstandalonepreambles\relax
    \newcommand{\subpreamble}[1]{}
    \let\endsubpreamble\relax
    \input{#1Preamble.sta}
}%

\UsePackage{main}

\begin{document}
    \question{%
        What does $1+1$ evaluates to?
    }
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not fully understanding your requirements. But I believe that the `\documentclass` needs to be set in the main file that you are compiling -- perhaps you should post a separate question for that to confirm.  My understanding of _preamble_ is that it is everything _after_ `\documentclass` and _before_ `\begin{document}`,and that is what this solution achieves.  Perhaps this is best done via a script outside of LaTeX, as per @AndrewStacey's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}   
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.hed}
% START YOUR HEADER HERE

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% whatever you want in your header
\def\WWW{World}

% END YOUR HEADER HERE
\end{filecontents}
\input{\jobname.hed}
\begin{document}

Hello \WWW!

\lipsum

\end{document}
```