# How to write the documentclass into a file

Tags: document-classes, external-files

Suppose I have received a selfcontained LaTeX source file, `main.tex`.
It includes a file of macro definitions, `my_macros.tex`, that the author
included in the preamble. This macro file is under my control, but,
besides beeing included by the author, shall not interfer with the LaTeXing
of the author.

To make it more precise: The file `my_macros.tex` may well be empty, on
the computer the author uses. But because the author is my customer,
he agreed to including it.
On my computer, I can fill `my_macros.tex` with whatever I like.

Is it possible to write some macros, and put them into `my_macros.tex`, that
do the following:

After issuing

```
$ latex main.tex
```

I'll find a file in my filesystem, say `main.nem`, that contains the documentclass
of the file `main.tex`.

So if for example `main.tex` looked like this

```
\documentclass{eth_super_article}
 % ...
 \input{my_macros.tex}
 % ....
 \begin{document}
 %....
 \end{document}
```

then `main.nem` will contain the line and only the line

```
\documentclass{eth_super_article}
```

Comment: Related Question: [How to write the preamble into a file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78949/how-to-write-the-preamble-into-a-file).

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73/which-document-class-is-being-used/43541#43541

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can assume that the users will never add `\RequirePackage` instructions before `\documentclass`, then the class name will be the first item in `\@filelist`.

```
\makeatletter
\def\hr@getclass#1.#2\@nil{\def\hr@class{#1}}
\expandafter\hr@getclass\@filelist\@nil
\immediate\openout\@partaux=\jobname.nem
\immediate\write\@partaux{%
  \noexpand\documentclass
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\\\@classoptionslist\\\else
  [\@classoptionslist]\fi{\hr@class}}
\immediate\closeout\@partaux
\makeatother
```

If the above restriction cannot be assumed something more is needed.

I abused `\@partaux` rather than allocating a new stream; it's used by `\include`, which should not appear in the preamble, so it seems quite safe.

---

An extended version that copes with possible `\RequirePackage` calls before `\documentclass`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\hr@getclass#1.#2,#3\@nil{%
  \def\hr@class{#1}\def\hr@ext{#2}\def\hr@filelist{#3}%
  \ifx\hr@ext\@clsextension
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {\expandafter\hr@getclass\hr@filelist,\@nil}%
}
\let\hr@filelist\@filelist               
\expandafter\hr@getclass\hr@filelist,\@nil
\immediate\openout\@partaux=\jobname.nem
\immediate\write\@partaux{%
  \noexpand\documentclass
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\\\@classoptionslist\\\else
  [\unexpanded\expandafter{\@classoptionslist}]\fi{\hr@class}}
\immediate\closeout\@partaux
\@onlypreamble\hr@getclass
\@onlypreamble\hr@class
\@onlypreamble\hr@ext
\@onlypreamble\hr@filelist
\makeatother
```

We start a recursion that ends when a file name of the form `filename.cls` is found, which surely is the main class; you're out of luck if one user says `\input{my_macros}` before `\documentclass`, of course.

Comment: @HeinzRasched We *need* `\def` here, as the macro has delimited arguments.

Comment: @HeinzRasched You didn't ask for the options. ;-) Fixed

Comment: @HeinzRasched I added also the version for devious users. `:)`

Comment: With *xkvltxp*, *kvoptions-patch*, *catoptions* or *skeyval-ltxpatch* loaded before `\documentclass`, `\@classoptionslist` can contain expandable tokens or undefined commands. So I have added `\unexpanded\expandafter{\@classoptionslist}` to your solution. Also, if a class file loads another class file with, e.g., `\LoadClass`, you may want to show all the loaded classes.

Comment: @AhmedMusa Thanks for this; my opinion is that using `\RequirePackage` before `\documentclass` should be used *very* sparingly (it changes `\jobname`, for instance). The OP wants to know the `\documentclass` line, so what the class does is unimportant. I really *don't* know why recording the line is needed, to be honest.